# Python field calculation completed but fails to populate new field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, field-calculator

Wrote a script to convert DD coordinates to DM coordinates. Results message says the script completed but field is still populated with Null.

[image: code used to convert coordinates and populate field]

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! As a new user please take the [tour]. Please [edit] your question to include your code as _text_ rather than as an image.  Having it as text means that potential answerers can copy/paste to test your code, as well as making it searchable so that others with similar questions can find your question in a search.

Comment: You're not `return`ing anything from your function...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The print statement in your function isn't doing what you think it's doing. Use `return DD` instead.

Comment: Tried that but it throws an error 999999

Comment: @sam.wats254 then that's your actual problem that you need to ask about

Comment: Aaaaand I figured it out.Man I'm tired of these small syntax errors. Thanks folks